# Finding a real function using boundary conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a region $R=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\}$. I want to find a real valued function $f$ which takes values $x$, $y$ where $f$ has boundary conditions: $1$ when $|z| = 1$ and $2$ when $|z| = 2$. We also have that $f$ is harmonic.

To start this I know $f$ has to be real, the real part of a complex logarithm is constant if $|z|$ is constant, so using the $\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ the only way this can be real is if we consider $\ln|z|$. We also know that $f$ is harmonic so $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$. I think I need to find a branch cut for $\ln|z|$ but I am unsure actually how this helps? Could someone help me out I don't really know how branch cuts come into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln |z|$ is harmonic in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ because it is locally the real part of any complex logarithm. Therefore
$$
 f(z) = 1 + \frac{\ln |z|}{\ln 2}
$$
is harmonic in $R$ and satisfies the given boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you, do you think you could add some detail on how you got this?

Comment: @LoliEvans: Which part is unclear? You essentially suggested in your question to consider $\ln |z|$ as a harmonic function. Then an affine transform $a + b \ln |z|$ is harmonic as well. Finally determine $a$ and $b$ such that the boundary conditions are satisfied. – This works because $R$ and the given boundary conditions are radially symmetric.